# How to random choice from a certain dictionary that was the user's input

Tags: python

I've been trying to create a program that tells me what to eat on a number of criteria. First it asks me whether preparation time should be low, average or high. It then asks me what type of food I want. It can also give me a type of meat to eat if I only want to know that.

```
import random
    pasta = {"tonijn": 0, "carbonara": 1, 'pittige': 0}
    speciaal = {'sucuk broden': 2, 'wraps': 1, 'ovenschotel': 2, 'bulgur met kip/gehakt': 1, 'bruschettas': 2,
                'zelf pizza': 2, 'kip tomaat ovenschotel': 2}
    fancy = {'biefstuk': 1, 'pizza bestellen': 0, 'doner bestellen': 0, "uiteten": 1}
    pittig = {'pittige pasta': 0}
    gezond = {'aardappel kip salade': 1, 'kipfilet, groente en bulgur': 0}
    ongezond = {"soep en pannenkoeken": 0, 'shoarma': 1}
    basis = {'avg': 1, "pasta": 0, 'curry': 1}
    vlees = ['schnitzel', 'varkenslapje', 'hoouthakkersburger', 'cordon bleu', 'kip krokant']

tijd = str(input("Prep time? Short, medium or long ")).lower()
print('Options:')
print('Pasta - Speciaal - Fancy - Pittig - Gezond - Ongezond - Basis - Welk vlees')
type_eten = str(input("Your choice: ")).lower()

if type_eten == 'welk vlees':
    print('The meat ur gonna eat: ', random.choice(vlees))
elif tijd == "short":
    for food, value in type_eten:
        mogelijke_opties = []
        if value < 1:
            mogelijke_opties.append(eten)
            antwoord = random.choice(mogelijke_opties)
            print("What ur gonna eat is: ", antwoord)
elif tijd == "medium":
    for food, value in type_eten:
        mogelijke_opties = []
        if waarde < 2:
            mogelijke_opties.append(eten)
            antwoord = random.choice(mogelijke_opties)
            print("Wat je gaat eten is: ", antwoord)
else:
    print('What ur gonna eat is: ', random.choice(list(type_eten)))
```

When I try to run this, it gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

for the code:

```
for food, value in type_eten.items():
```

I first created a dictionary in which the short prep time meals have a 0 as a value, medium 1 and long 2. It then asks the user what he/she wants. If they only want to know what meat they're gonna eat, it'll give them that. Otherwise it checks the prep time and creates a new list with the types of food that are in a certain dictionary with the corresponding prep time. I then want it to choose something from that new list. To do that, I think I should be able to add at .items() after 'type_eten', so it would look like this;

```
elif tijd == "short":
        for food, value in type_eten.items():
            mogelijke_opties = []
            if value < 1:
                mogelijke_opties.append(eten)
                antwoord = random.choice(mogelijke_opties)
                print("What ur gonna eat is: ", antwoord)
```

I don't know whether that would solve the problem but after some research on stackoverflow, I think it should. type_eten doesn't give me the possibility however and I'd have to add all the dictionary names which would make the code a lot longer. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Let's take a step back here, have you been testing and debugging your code as you write it? What do you understand from that error message? Speaking of, please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Apart from some typos and language errors, there's a few logic errors in your program. The error itself is caused by treating a string (`type_eten`) as a dictionary (by calling `.items()` on it) - a string does not have an `items()` function, so it fails. But if you go through your code 'by hand' you'll find that there's many options the user can choose that don't give the desired output. For example, you don't use `vlees` after getting it and getting it probably isn't mutually exclusive with the preparation time. Also, you'd be print all the types of food that match the selected type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you're confusing the internal variable names with external data.

```
if type_eten == 'welk vlees':
    print('The meat ur gonna eat: ', random.choice(vlees))
elif tijd == "short":
    for food, value in type_eten:
```

`type_eten` is a string.  Just because you gave an internal variable that name does *not* make them correspond; "pittig" is a string; `pittig` is a dict.

Instead, save your design by making the dictionary that you're actually trying to use:

```
menu = {
    "pasta": {"tonijn": 0, "carbonara": 1, 'pittige': 0},
    "speciaal": {'sucuk broden': 2, 'wraps': 1, 'ovenschotel': 2,
                 'bulgur met kip/gehakt': 1, 'bruschettas': 2,
                 'zelf pizza': 2, 'kip tomaat ovenschotel': 2},
    "fancy": {'biefstuk': 1, 'pizza bestellen': 0, 'doner bestellen': 0, "uiteten": 1},
    ... u.s.w.
}
...
    for food, value in menu[type_eten].items():
```

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes this almost worked, thanks! The only thing I had to add was .items() after menu[type_eten]